# kernel is outdated

Tags: apt, kernel, updates

I have troubles with updating my kernel. I'm running Kubuntu 14.04. `uname -r` output:

```
3.13.0-32-generic
```

I clearly see newer versions in repos with `sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'`:

```
...
linux-headers-3.13.0-40 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.13.0-40-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
...
```

Also, when I was upgrading my system with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I've noticed the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-34 linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-35 linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-37 linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-39 linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
...
```

All those kernels are newer than mine also, but for some reason, system decided to keep mine instead.

I had similar problem before. That time I've made some weird tricks with manual installation of header packages, but I think there should be nicer way to get system on track with kernel updating.

**Edit:**
Here are my `/boot` contents that clearly show that there are no newer kernels installed: `ls /boot`

```
abi-3.13.0-27-generic     config-3.2.0-61-generic       memtest86+.bin                System.map-3.2.0-61-generic
abi-3.13.0-32-generic     grub                          memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-3.13.0-27-generic
abi-3.2.0-61-generic      initrd.img-3.13.0-27-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin      vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
config-3.13.0-27-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic  System.map-3.13.0-27-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
config-3.13.0-32-generic  initrd.img-3.2.0-61-generic   System.map-3.13.0-32-generic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the system decides to hold back a kernel upgrade, it has its reasons...  (Like you have Oracle's VirtualBox with drivers compiled for your kernel or similar low-level software installed)

That being said, if you *do* want to upgrade your kernel:

1. Do a full system backup (I use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/))
2. just install the latest version by:

   `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`

Comment: Yes, you were right that the system has its reasons to hold back the updates. When I did the `apt-get install linux-generic`, it rebooted with new kernel and... the weird video artifact, splitting screen into 3 parts. So I reverted things back. Probably it's because I'm running this system as a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you did not rebooted your system.

Currently you are running `3.13.0-32`. The latest kernel version is `3.13.0-40`. 
After reboot the system will boot in the latest. So all intermediate versions will never be used and can be removed.

I suggest to use autoremove (`sudo apt-get autoremove`), then reboot the system and watch if the it has booted to the latest kernel. Finally run autoremove again to erase the currently running.

Comment: Miss. Tried to autoremove, reboot, still no success. Also, look at my `/boot` contents (I've added in the edit), there are no newer kernels.

Comment: The latest kernel for 14.04 is `2.13.0-40`. Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade` and check if it is installed. If yes then reboot again.

Comment: No, no updates were installed.